# Android:Download images from their path and show in gridview

Tags: android, image

I am making an app in which i have parsed the xml response which contain image path and its description and now i have  to **download images from their path** and then **show images in gridview**.I tried my links but couldnot found anything relevant.Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

```
and the response is:

ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a19.png
```

03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a16.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a15.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a13.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a12.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a11.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a10.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a9.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a8.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a7.png
03-19 14:57:13.460: I/System.out(13878): ImagePath: http://apsolutions.com/amazing/explore/a6.png

Comment: when u say path, do u mean url?

Comment: path is local or from external web server ??

Comment: when i parse the response i get the url in arraylist, now i want to know that how to use that arraykist to get images

Answer (score 0):

**Here is solution..**

```
URL url = new URL ("url/anImage.png");
InputStream input = url.openStream();
try {

    String storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream (storagePath + "/myImage.png");
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[aReasonableSize];
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    } finally {
        output.close();
    }
} finally {
    input.close();
}
```

Comment: when i parse the response i get the url in arraylist, now i want to know that how to use that arraykist to get images

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you get an arraylist of urls.

1. u need to make an image downloader using either HttpUrlConnection or Apache Client. (Search for lazyimage downloader). Implement a listener in this which can call a function once download is complete.
2. Send requests to receive the images.
3. Make viewholders for your gridview and in your viewholder, implement the listener for ure image downloader. In the listener set the image in your imageview.

Comment: How to put arraylist in http and download images and show them

Comment: here is a link to lazy image loader.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012

Comment: Can you post the response u r getting? I mean the xml/arraylist.

Comment: Ok, so loop through the array list and call the image downloader for each of them